# Integral of $h(z)h'(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $h$ is analytic on the region below (the two white points are dug out) and $\int_{\alpha}h(z)dz=3$, $\int_{\beta}h(z)dz=4$, then what's $\int_{\gamma}h(z)h'(z)dz$?

I am thinking using $\int_{h(\gamma)}zdz$...but can't find any theorems to apply.

[image]

Comment: @Aaron Since the antiderivative of $hh'$ is $\frac12h^2$, which is analytic, what do you suppose the value of the integral of interest is?

Comment: @MarkViola Actually, thinking about things more carefully, if we write out a Laurent series for $h^2$, it's derivative will not have any $z^{-1}$ terms, and we don't have to use the information at the poles.  However, I feel a little uncertain about this answer.

Comment: @Aaron $h^2$ can have a $\frac1z$ term.  But, $hh'$ cannot and does not.

Comment: @MarkViola I can reach the same conclusion with another argument (I think....need to verify details) by converting the path integral into an elementary integral and using the existence of an anti-derivative to appeal to the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I was initially convinced that was wrong too, because it didn't make use of the information at the singularities.

Comment: @Aaron Those singularities do not lead to a residue of $hh'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that $h$ is analytic on $\gamma$ and the antiderivative of $h(z)h'(z)$ is $\frac12 h^2(z)$on $\gamma$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what theorem can be applied on analytic antiderivative. Can you be more specific?

Comment: What happens when you evaluate $\frac12h^2(z)$ at the coincidental endpoints of the integral over $\gamma$.

Comment: Do you want to apply newton leibniz formula? But it requires the region to be simply connected

Comment: @danny Try writing $h(z)$ as a Laurent series.  Find its derivative $h'(z)$ as a Laurent series.  Multiply $h(z)$ by $h'(z)$.  Is there a non-zero coefficient on the $1/z$ term?

Comment: What if $h(z)=1/z+1+z+z^2$?

Comment: @DannyIf $h(z)=\frac1z+1+z+z^2$, then $h'(z)=-\frac1{z^2}+1+2z$ and $$\begin{align}
h(z)h'(z)&=-\frac1{z^3}-\frac1{z^2}+2+3z+3z^2+2z^3
\end{align}$$which has no $\frac1z$ term.

Comment: I wonder why it's related to the antiderivative $h^2(z)/2$?

Comment: @Danny $$\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac12h^2(z)\right)=h(z)h'(z)$$

Comment: I know that, my question is your claim is just $h(z)h'(z)$ doesn't have $1/z$ term, but why do you need to consider its antiderivative?

Comment: @Danny You've asked questions that prompted the corresponding replies.  So, I am unsure as to the meaning of this last question.  One can either show that $hh'$ has no $\frac1z$ term OR use the fact that $hh'=\frac12 (h^2)'$.

Comment: I feel very confused, you use the fact that hh' doesn't have 1/z term to show the residue is 0, thus the integral is 0.  Where do we need the fact $hh′=12(h2)′$?

Comment: @Danny He showed that $hh'$ didn't have a $1/z$ term in that example.  The assertion is that nothing with an antiderivative can have a $1/z$ term, because the only way to take a derivative and get $1/z$ is by having $\log z$, which would prevent you from being holomorphic on your domain.

Comment: @Danny I don't use the fact that $hh'$ has no $\frac1z$ like term.  I simply use the fact that $hh'=\frac12 (h^2)'$ and that $\int_{z_1}^{z_2}f'(z)\,dz=f(z_2)-f(z_1)$.

Comment: In order to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, don't we need to require the region to be simply-connected?

Comment: @danny Carve out the two singularities to form a new region that is simply connected.  Then, pick any two distinct points. $z_1$ and $z_2$ on $\gamma$.  Clearly, we can use $\int_{z_1}^{z_2}f'(z)\,dz =f(z_2)-f(z_1)$ as we traverse $\gamma$ from $z_1$ to $z_2$.  And it doesn't matter if we traverse counter clockwise or clockwise.  Hence, $\oint_\gamma f'(z)\,dz=0$.